# 'bash' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, reactjs, bash, npm

i have an error in installing react-flux-starter-kit-windows.
i have installed latest node.js and npm
when i am using this command :
npm install -g react-flux-starter-kit
it gives me following error

```
react-flux-starter-kit@1.1.4 postinstall C:\Users\Hardik\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-flux-starter-kit
bash setup.sh
'bash' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\Hardik\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "react-flux-starter-kit"
npm ERR! node v6.9.5
npm ERR! npm v4.2.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! react-flux-starter-kit@1.1.4 postinstall: bash setup.sh
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the react-flux-starter-kit@1.1.4 postinstall script 'bash setup.sh'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the react-flux-starter-kit package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR! bash setup.sh
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR! npm bugs react-flux-starter-kit
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR! npm owner ls react-flux-starter-kit
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR! C:\Users\Hardik\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-02-22T10_01_48_356Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems that it needs Bash installed. If you're using Windows then you may be able to install it using one of:

- https://git-for-windows.github.io/
- https://www.cygwin.com/
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about
- http://win-bash.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 4):

The same error can appear if the bash isn't present in `path` env, so you need to add it manually.
Add this directory to your `path` env:
`C:\Program Files\Git\bin`

Answer (score 3):

Go with the steps

Setting->update->for developers->developers mood->on->yes.
Control Panel->programs & features->Turn windows features on or off->Windows subsystem for linux->restart computer.

Comment: It was helpful but I still was not able to solve the problem completely. I had to install ubuntu app afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

To fix this on Windows, if you install git for windows you will get `git.exe` at this directory:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
```

but the file is `git.exe` and you need `bash.exe` for Windows.

So [use this to create a doskey](https://superuser.com/questions/560519/how-to-set-an-alias-in-windows-command-line) alias to bash command

```
doskey bash=git
```

Now type `bash` at command line and you should see the help output from `git.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it in 2 stages:
First, I turned on the 'Developer Mode' (Settings -> Update and Security -> For developers).
Second, I installed Ubuntu app from Microsoft Store, then ran Command Prompt as  administrator and typed bash and set a username and password.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows then you may be able to use GIT Bash which you probably already have it installed or get it from https://gitforwindows.org/ instead of using Windows Command Prompt or Windows PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

You can run bash command with git-bash.exe. You can find git-bash.exe in "C:\Program Files\Git" directory.