# Running a github repository locally in Anaconda

Tags: python, github, anaconda, repository

I am new to cloning Github repository and executing the projects, so I am facing problems to run a project in Anaconda
https://github.com/MalongTech/research-charnet

This is the repository. I read the instructions, but while downloading weights the terminal is showing an error of bash is not an internal command and I am stuck. Also, I am unable to comprehend the instructions properly. Can anyone please help in step-by-step guidance from cloning this to running the code.
Python-3.7.6
Pytorch=1.4.0
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you clone successfully, if not The command is `git clone https://github.com/MalongTech/research-charnet.git`.  You may be prompted to enter your github username and password again.  After its successful try following the README.md markdown it gives you command by command you should be able to copy paste into the command line.

The error sounds like you are running in windows and that project is made to run in Linux.  Bash is a core Linux command.  If that is the case follow this question. 
[Bash command not found from stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42438587/bash-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: Thank you for your help. But now I have to install wget, for that do I need to install yum

Comment: I believe wget is a generic downloader for all Linux distributions.  Yum is the package installer for centos and red hat Linux.  Cygwin is an Linux emulator. To install wget in Cygwin you have to re-run the installer and select wget from utilities during your installation.  Scan the entire readme for what you need then make a list, and then select all the tools you need so you don’t have to keep reinstalling.